# converting TXT to CSV python

Tags: python, csv

I have a txt data. it looks as follows

```
time pos
0.02 1
0.1 2
 ...
```

and so on. so the each line is separated with a space. I need to convert it in to a CSV file. like

```
time,pos
0.02,1
0.1,2
0.15,3
```

How can I do it with python ? This is what I have tried

```
time = []
pos = []

def get_data(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
        csvFileReader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        next(csvFileReader)
        for row in csvFileReader:
            time.append((row[0].split(' ')[0]))
            pos.append((row[1]))
    return
```

Comment: whats the problem in your code?

Comment: Does your file have any quoted arguments containing spaces?  If not, would it suffice to just do `line.replace(' ', ',')`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
with open(filename) as infile, open('outfile.csv','w') as outfile: 
    for line in infile: 
        outfile.write(line.replace(' ',','))
```

Comment: Thanks, more pythonic :D

Comment: you have to append `\n` at the end of every line

Comment: with your new edit `'_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'writeline'`

Comment: I'm getting languages mixed up. It should work as it is now.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html):

```
import csv
with open(filename, newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ')
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

For writing just use default options and it would save file with comma as a delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
import pandas as pd
with open(filename, 'r') as fo:
    data = fo.readlines()
    for d in range(len(data)):
        if d==0:
            column_headings = data[d].split()
        data_to_insert = data[d].split()
        pd.DataFrame(data_to_insert).to_excel('csv_file.csv', header=False, index=False, columns = column_headings))
```

Comment: TypeError: writelines() takes exactly one argument (0 given)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
import csv
time = []
pos = []

def get_data(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
        csvfile1 = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
        with open(filename.replace('.txt','.csv'), 'w') as csvfile:
            writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
            for row in csvfile1:
                writer.writerow(row)
```