# Merging multiple similar tables together with missing items and value

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

Please help. I need to combine a lot of `.txt` files into 1 summary `.txt` file. For example, my 1st file:

```
Name1
A    1
B    4
C    5
```

my 2nd file:

```
Name2
A    3
D    2
E    1
```

I need to make a file like this:

```
    Name1    Name2
A    1        3
B    4        0
C    5        0
D    0        2
E    0        1
```

As you can see, my 2 files have similar format but they have both common `(A)` and unique `(B,C,D,E)` components. To combine them together, I am thinking about making dictionaries which take `Name1` and `Name2` as dictionaries' names. However, I do not know how to dynamically pass name for the dictionaries if I have like 100 files.
After that, I am thinking about creating a common dictionary which has all the keys from every file. Then, I will compare my keys from each file to that common dictionary, any missing keys will be added with value 0.
I don't know what to do next to make it print into the format that I want.

Comment: You should look into pandas. Create a dataframe with components (`A`, `B`, `C`, ...) as your index and your files (`Name1`, `Name2`) as your columns.

Comment: Thank you, I have never used pandas before. I will take a look at it :)

Comment: No problem. If you find yourself really struggling with something, just come back and search the site or post a question!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `pandas` for dataframe operations.
Here's the solution using pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name1':[1,4,5]}, index=['A','B','C'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name2':[3,2,1]}, index=['A','D','E'])

df_new = df1.join(df2, how='outer')
df_new.fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
    name1   name2
A   1.0     3.0
B   4.0     0.0
C   5.0     0.0
D   0.0     2.0
E   0.0     1.0
```

**Edit**

First convert your `.txt` files into `csv` or `tsv` files to be read by pandas using `pd.read_csv()`

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try your solutions. I am quite new to Python and I have around 100 files so I will think about making it more automatically.

Comment: Then look at this link [txt to csv converter using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50101543/converting-txt-to-csv-python)